# В числе нечетные биты сделать равными 0, а четные оставить прежними

Tags: c++, битовые-операции

Программа должна получить число типа `unsigned short int` и в нем нечетные биты сделать равными 0, а четные оставить прежними.

**Пример:**
при вводе

```
1111 1110 1010 1100
```

должно получиться

```
0101 0100 0000 0100
```

Решение требуется на С++ с использованием побитовых операций.

Заранее спасибо!

Вот что я сделал на данный момент:

```
unsigned short int nechet0(int x){
    return x & 0xA0A0;
}
```

Comment: А с какой стороны считаем?

Comment: Почему 0xA0A0? Напишите число, в котором нечетные биты нулевые, а четные - единичные. Как оно выглядит?

Comment: @Harry насчет 0xA0A0 - я еще пробовал 0xAAAA, но оно четные биты делает равными 0, а нечетные оставляет прежними

Comment: @AlexeyTen Считаем слева, судя по примеру

Comment: Послушайте, давайте не гадайте... так мы будем долго перебирать... еще раз — **запишите число, в котором нечетные биты нулевые, а четные - единичные**. В двоичном виде. Потом уже будете переводить в шестнадцатеричное или в какое там хотите...

Answer (score 0):

Набросал по быстрому, сам в основном работаю с микроконтроллерами (типы данных uint16_t, uint8_t), здесь почему-то компилятор ругался на них, типы взял интуитивно подходящие short int и т.д.

```
#define SET_BIT(REG, BIT)     ((REG) |= (BIT))
#define CLEAR_BIT(REG, BIT)   ((REG) &= ~(BIT))
#define READ_BIT(REG, BIT)    ((REG) & (BIT))

int main()
{
    short int a = 0xFEAC;
    short cnt = 1;//четное либо не четное, либо поменять условие
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) * 8; i++)
    {
        cnt ^= 1;

        if (cnt)
        {
            if (READ_BIT(a, 1 << i))
                a= CLEAR_BIT(a, 1 << i);
            //else
            //  a= SET_BIT(a, 1 << i);
        }
    }
    printf("%hu\n", a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Если слегка упростить приведённый код, то получится `a = a & 0x5555;`.

Comment: Я только не понял, это был "стёб"? Ну, то есть решение работающее, но такое, что его никак применять или сдать преподу нельзя? :)